# How to Inflate view from XML in Android?

Tags: android, user-interface, view, android-tablelayout, android-inflate

I'm creating a tableLayout [given in XML]

adding table Row [created in XML and inflating in Java]

also adding 2 textview to the table Row [created in XML and inflating in JAVA]

I'm able to get only the background and textcolors but not the layout properties like width, height and margin to get table view.

Comment: Please post your code of xml file and the java where you inflating it

Comment: As you have mentioned that you are having 2 textviews per table row, then i would suggest you to implement a ListView with custom adapter.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="400dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="2dip"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:textColor="@color/white" />

Answer (score 57):

1. First declare your inflater.

   ```
   LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getApplicationContext().getSystemService
     (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
   ```
2. Identify and inflate the new view you seek to project on the current view.

   ```
   View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.new_layout,null);
   ```
3. You would want to add your new inflated view to your layout.

   ```
   main.addView(view);
   ```

You can reference additional information here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html

**Update May 2019 (Kotlin):**
This is how you would inflate a view from XML in Kotlin. this is referring to an activity.

```
val view = this.layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_upgrade, null)
mainLayout.addView(view)
```

Answer (score 13):

```
LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext());
View cv = li.inflate(R.layout.your_layout, null);

mainlayout.addView(cv);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getApplicationContext().getSystemService      (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layout,null);
mainlayout.addView(view;
```

follow the above to inflate view.

Comment: how to get mainLayout? We are setting setContentView(layout) in onCreate()

Comment: mainlayout will be your tableLayout instance in your case

Comment: yeah I got your point and did the same way.. I can get the View Component [TextView] in screen but applying only bg and text color and not the layout properties as I given in the above comment

Comment: you can layout param to apply width,height, and margin

Comment: I done with that but I m not able to get the textview components with right spacing