# Error in Change Textview?

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, textview

I would like to ask why I'm getting an error on setting the text of `TextView`. I'm viewing here the beginner layout, but the textview is in my gameplay layout. Is that possible? Here is my code:

```
public class Beginner extends Activity 
{

    Button beginner1, beginner2;
    TextView category;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle MainPage) 
    {
        super.onCreate(MainPage);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.beginner);

        beginner1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnBeginner1);
        beginner2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnBeginner2);

        beginner1.setOnClickListener(myOnlyhandler);
        beginner2.setOnClickListener(myOnlyhandler);

        category = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvCategory);

    }

    View.OnClickListener myOnlyhandler = new View.OnClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch(v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btnBeginner1:
            Intent openBeginner = new Intent("com.thesis.logipic.GAMEPLAY");
            startActivity(openBeginner);
            category.setText("Category");
        break;
        case R.id.btnBeginner2:
            Intent openBeginner2 = new Intent("com.thesis.logipic.GAMEPLAY");
            startActivity(openBeginner2);  
            category.setText("Category");
        break;
        }
    }
    };

}
```

And this is the error from my Logcat:

```
10-08 21:26:30.486: D/AndroidRuntime(1019): Shutting down VM
10-08 21:26:30.486: W/dalvikvm(1019): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
10-08 21:26:30.506: E/AndroidRuntime(1019): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-08 21:26:30.506: E/AndroidRuntime(1019): java.lang.NullPointerException
10-08 21:26:30.506: E/AndroidRuntime(1019):     at com.thesis.logipic.Beginner$1.onClick(Beginner.java:42)
10-08 21:26:30.506: E/AndroidRuntime(1019):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
10-08 21:26:30.506: E/AndroidRuntime(1019):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
10-08 21:26:30.506: E/AndroidRuntime(1019):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
10-08 21:26:30.506: E/AndroidRuntime(1019):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-08 21:26:30.506: E/AndroidRuntime(1019):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
10-08 21:26:30.506: E/AndroidRuntime(1019):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
10-08 21:26:30.506: E/AndroidRuntime(1019):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-08 21:26:30.506: E/AndroidRuntime(1019):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
10-08 21:26:30.506: E/AndroidRuntime(1019):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
10-08 21:26:30.506: E/AndroidRuntime(1019):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
10-08 21:26:30.506: E/AndroidRuntime(1019):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-08 21:26:32.466: I/Process(1019): Sending signal. PID: 1019 SIG: 9
```

Comment: as you said you are trying to access TextView which is in seperate xml resource, I dont't think it's possible. Try to create TextView programaticaly in your Beginner.java

Comment: what is on line 42 of Beginner.java ?

Comment: I think line 42 is: `category.setText("Category");`, NPE due to category `TextView` is not existed in `beginner` layout.

Comment: I think `R.id.tvCategory` is not in same layout xml, its a reason of NPE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your TextView has to be in the layout that you set in `onCreate()` using `setContentView()`. You get **`NullPointerException`** because you try to find view which is not part of you layout.

If you want to add view to your layout, you can do this programmatically. You have to create your view programmatically and then add it to your layout using [`yourLayout.addView(textView, params)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10419021/1726308).

You have two options to crete view:

1. Create the view using its constructor and methods.
2. Inflate view using `LayoutInflater`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19110502/1726308). But if you want to do this, your `TextView` has to be in new layout (category_layout.xml) and it has to be the top level view (you don't have to place it in other layout).

Answer (score 0):

put category.setText("Category") before startActivity()

Comment: tried it even w/out the
Intent openBeginner = new Intent("com.thesis.logipic.GAMEPLAY");
            startActivity(openBeginner);
still got the same error

Answer (score 0):

this not possible to access to other resource that you didn't initialize it in setContentView. tell me why you didn't use it in the same Layout?

Comment: because it should just change the text of the game in another layout its like this is the category and the other layout is where the question is something like that

Answer (score 0):

As you said its in a different layout. In order to access it you have to inflate it first.

Or you could just move your TextView into the R.layout.beginner layout.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing a reference through ID of a TextView "**tvCategory**" that is NOT in the **beginner** layout that you were inflated. Why you don't do this once the second activity is loaded? or by default inside the XML?