# How to use YogaLayout

Tags: android

i run the yogalayout android sample
https://github.com/facebook/yoga/tree/master/android/sample

this sample's layouts use xml like

```
<com.facebook.yoga.android.YogaLayout>
    <ImageView />
    <ImageView />
</com.facebook.yoga.android.YogaLayout>
```

**i want to use java code to write layout**,but how to write?
YogaNode just calculate the layoutX and layoutY , how to add view to its parent?
i see the source code,and found i can get the layout's YogaNode
and use it to set params
such as node.setFlexXXXXXX()

so, now i write code like this:

```
layout.addView(view);//addView to YogaLayout
node =  ((YogaLayout)layout).getYogaNode().getChildAt(layout.indexOfChild(view));//get Node
node.setFlexDirection();//set params
```

but VirtualYogaLayout doesnt work
when add virtualyogalayout it clears its children
can someone give me a sample?

Comment: Have you read this doc https://facebook.github.io/yoga/docs/api/android/

Comment: yes, i read it. but it doesnt tell me how to use java to write layout

Comment: @North-morning in android, the term for making a layout view into a Java object is called: inflating. You will need to use the LayoutInflater. Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19110502/1371041